# How to initialize shift registers in polyphase filter based resamplers to avoid or compensate for group delay?

Tags: filters, filter-design, resampling, group-delay, polyphase

I have a signal **a** = [a(t<sub>0</sub>),a(t<sub>1</sub>),a(t<sub>2</sub>),..,a(t<sub>N-2</sub>),a(t<sub>N-1</sub>)]

I'm using a *polyphase filter* based *resampler* with filter length $L$ of $8$, fixed interpolation rate $I$ of $10000$ and decimation rate of $D$ to resample the signal $a$. After resampling, I'm seeing a group delay of $N = \frac{L \times I}{2 D}$ samples.

I'm able to partially compensate for the group delay by initializing shift register **S** with the samples of the signal **a** in the following configuration,

**S** = [a(t<sub>0</sub>),a(t<sub>1</sub>),a(t<sub>2</sub>),a(t<sub>3</sub>),a(t<sub>0</sub>),a(t<sub>1</sub>),a(t<sub>2</sub>),a(t<sub>3</sub>)]

The above configuration compensates for the group delay, but does not reconstruct the signal from t<sub>0</sub> to t<sub>4</sub> accurately. What would be the ideal way to initialize the shift register to reconstruct the signal with better accuracy?